# JProfiler Error: The IDE could not locate the selected class

Tags: jprofiler

I am facing a problem in J Profiler when I click on view source I get some error saying  The IDE could not locate the selected class and unable to view source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach source code to Jprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529580/attach-source-code-to-jprofiler)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the session settings, select the "Application Settings" tab, select the "Source path" radio button in the "Java File Path" section, and add your source file roots there.

An alternative is to start the profiling session from your IDE (with the appropriate JProfiler plugin), then the source code navigation will be in the IDE and you don't have to configure anything.