# Unable to view the source code from Jprofiler

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am getting the error (**Source file could not be found in source path**) while trying to view the source code in Jprofiler for selected object.

Referring to the question [JProfiler Error: The IDE could not locate the selected class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060282/jprofiler-error-the-ide-could-not-locate-the-selected-class)

I followed the suggested answer and I added the source code path (i.e. the deployment path) but still problem still occurred.

**Further details:**
I am attaching Jprofiler to a running JVM process (weblogic 10.3.6)

Comment: `the source code path (i.e. the deployment path)` That does not sound correct. The source code path has nothing to do with deployment. It's the root directory of your source files.

Comment: @IngoKegel By that I am referring to the war file location which has been used while deploying the war file in weblogic server. If this is not the source path, then where it is ?

Comment: "Source" as in "source code". The WAR file does not contain any source files.